# How to link Tags in typo3 tx_news?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want to link my tags in my news http://www.sbo-guetersloh.de/mitteilungen therfor I added links with this additional: ?tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]=3
But when I follow this link I get still all news. Do I have to change anything in the configuration or do I have to chanhge anything in the files?
typo3 8.7.15, tx_news 7.0.4

greets
Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page where you have the list plugin installed, uncheck the

**Disable override demand** Checkbox

in the correpsonding plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the "Disable override demand" in the plugin and everything is ok'
I did't find it course of the translation.

Volker